# Making calculations in another cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Ok, so  I have this excel question.
I kept on trying to resolve it like this or with similar methods, like typing the number in a cell and selecting it, but I always get the `#VALUE!` error.

Do you have any idea what could be the solution for this?  Thank you!

[image: Excel picture]

Comment: You're trying to multiply by a string. What happens if you remove the quotes from `"0.0175"`?

Comment: The quotes add automatically for some reason. I tried deleting them and I get the "there's a problem with this formula" message.

Comment: Does changing the semicolons to commas change anything? I think there's some regional variation to their acceptability. Also, is C4 the numeric value `200000` or the string value `$200.000`?

Comment: Changing the semicolons to comma also give the "there's a problem with the formula" error. For all the functions I used before I used semicolons since comas don't seem to work; also, c4 is the numeric value

Comment: Try retyping the formula from scratch without the quotes.

Comment: try 0,0175 with comma but not with a dot.

Comment: It worked, finally! It was the comma instead of the dot. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 2):

I think it may be your `0.0175`, because it seems that you use `dot ( . )` as thousand-seperator, ergo much you use `comma ( , )` as decimal-sign. Try changing to `0,0175`

That being said, why are you writing `"0.0175"` as if it were a string and not a decimal? Remove the `"-signs`.